# Ollydbg can't disassemble code but runs when I open the .exe file

Tags: assembly, reverse, disassembly, ollydbg

I have a simple C++ and C# code which is basically like any other crackme tutorial for ollydbg.

Just a textbox and a button which checks if I inputted the correct serial key.  Unfortunately when I run it in Ollydbg, the program runs but there is no disassembly (unless I exit the program).

**I would just like to know why there is no disassembly shown.**

I'm using OllyDbg 32bit (which I downloaded from legendofr4ndom forums).

My OS is Win8 64bit but I can still run and patch the crackme tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

.NET uses an intermediate language, not native assembler instructions, so disassembling cannot be done the "usual" way. Even Microsoft's debugger WinDbg does not disassemble .NET code without a special plugin (called SOS).

So unfortunately, OllyDbg cannot disassemble your .NET code. However, you should be able to see and disassemble the entry points of the .NET framework. But that'll not be very helpful for reverse engineering a .NET application.

Answer (score 1):

Which version of Olly did you use ?????

Olly1 -> does not disassemble .net program and run through the application.
Try .net Reflector in that case

OR

use Olly2 -> which can disassemble .net program